# auto_prepend_file is not working in cli mode

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I cannot get an auto_prepend_file run on my mac:

```
# cat /opt/local/lib/php/test.php
<?php
function test() { return 'foo'; }

# php --ini | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/local/etc/php5
Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/local/etc/php5/php.ini

# cat /opt/local/etc/php5/php.ini | grep auto_prepend_file
auto_prepend_file = "/opt/local/lib/php/test.php"

# ls -la /opt/local/etc/php5/php.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  68630 Jul 27 13:53 /opt/local/etc/php5/php.ini

# php -r "echo ini_get('auto_prepend_file');"
/opt/local/lib/php/test.php
```

But then...

```
# php -r "echo test();"
Fatal error: Call to undefined function test() in Command line code on line 1

# php -i | grep auto_prepend_file
auto_prepend_file => /opt/local/lib/php/test.php => /opt/local/lib/php/test.php
```

It works through the (restarted) apache.

Do you have any idea what I could have made wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to call a script from CLI? I didn't see this behaviour before, but I assume, that `auto_prepend_file` only prepends a file before the script is called. In your case you don't call a script at all, thus `auto_prepend_file` is not executed. Just a guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`auto_prepend_file` is not executed when you run code directly through the `-r` commandline switch. It works fine when you execute PHP files on the commandline, regardless if PHP itself is called from the CLI or it is specified in the shebang of the executable file.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that in this minute when I ran phpunit.

Answer (score 3):

This is documented behavior:

> This option is only intended for very basic code, so some
>   configuration directives (such as auto_prepend_file and
>   auto_append_file) are ignored in this mode.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to pipe the file content you want to execute to `php` instead of using `-r`. E.g.:

```
echo "<?php dump('anuise');" | php
```